# Dynamic audit table creation via Migrations

Tags: entity-framework-core-2.1, audit.net

Using .Net Core 2.1 and Audit.NET EF 12.1.10, I'm trying to add a migration that includes the audit tables but when invoking Add-Migration, no audit tables are generated in the migration.  I assumed that using the "dynamic" audit will do this automagically.  I don't have any audit interfaces-- I am leaving this up to Audit.NET.  Below is in my Startup:

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
            .ForContext<MainDbContext>(config => config
                .IncludeEntityObjects()
                .AuditEventType("{context}:{database}"))
            .UseOptOut()
            .IgnoreAny(entity => entity.Name.StartsWith("AspNet") && entity.Name.StartsWith("OI"));


        Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
            .UseEntityFramework(ef => ef
                .AuditTypeNameMapper(typeName => "Audit_" + typeName)
                .AuditEntityAction((evt, entry, auditEntity) =>
                {
                    // Get the current HttpContext 
                    var httpContext = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

                    // Store the identity name on the "UserName" property of the audit entity
                    ((dynamic)auditEntity).UserName = httpContext.User?.Identity.Name;
                    ((dynamic)auditEntity).AuditDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    ((dynamic)auditEntity).AuditAction = entry.Action;
                }));
```

My DbContext extending from AuditIdentityDbContext:

```
public class MainDbContext : AuditIdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>
```

I only have one entity so far, called Activity, just to test this out and I would expect Add-Migrations to include an Audit_Activity table as well as the Activity table, but I only got the latter.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The library does not provide any custom migration. If you included the audit tables on your model, the normal EF migrations flow should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

I tried Auditing Identity Roles just because it was easiest to test at the moment

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
}

public class Audit_ApplicationRole : IAudit
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(256)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(256)")]
    public string NormalizedName { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    public ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    public string RoleId  { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(100)")]
    public string AuditUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime AuditDate { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(7)")]
    public string Action { get; set; } // "Insert", "Update" or "Delete"
}

public interface IAudit
{
    string AuditUser { get; set; }
    DateTime AuditDate { get; set; }
    string Action { get; set; } 
}
```

Then I used your code in StartUp.cs

```
        Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
            .ForContext<ApplicationDbContext>(config => config
                .IncludeEntityObjects()
                .AuditEventType("{context}:{database}"));

        Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
            .UseEntityFramework(x => x
                .AuditTypeNameMapper(typeName => "Audit_" + typeName)
                .AuditEntityAction<IAudit>((ev, ent, auditEntity) =>
                {
                    auditEntity.AuditDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    auditEntity.AuditUser = ev.Environment.UserName;
                    auditEntity.Action = ent.Action;
                }));
```

What I found out is that the Id had to be string for some reason, it could not be int.

Screenshot from the link shows that the changes in data have saved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTOuA.png)

On the side note, I wanted to save the user logged in via Identity, so in case anyone wondering, this post helped me achieve it.
https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/49799223/asp-net-core-entity-changing-history